# excel to .XBRL converter

Tags: c#

I am currently working on new programs that converts Excel Files to XBRL using the C# language (or any programming language).
As I read over the net, XBRL is following XML schema and it's where financial system are heading to, where all this institution wanted to have their own standard language.
There are ready to use software for this in the market but the client we have today requires us to write a program just for them.

Has anyone here in the forum had written a program similar to my need?

Comment: As currently written, this question isn't really on topic for stack overflow.  From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), your question must be about *a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers; and is **a practical, answerable problem** that is unique to software development*. But you aren't asking a question that is practical and answerable, you're asking for people to share their experiences implementing a certain kind of application. That's likely to be closed as needing details or clarity.

Comment: See also [ask] and the [tour] for how to ask questions here.

Answer (score 0):

XBRL has their own (lengthy) format specification, [which you can find here.](https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html) Excel isn't innately compatible with that, unless you have a specific template or usage pattern in mind. There have been a number of "Excel to XBRL" scripts, but it appears as if they're all just a custom Excel document with a script that can generate the compliant XBRL or iXBRL document.

It's likely that you're going to need to map the requirements of the customer to the XBRL output they need, and I'm not aware of a .NET library that does that as it stands. I hate to deliver the bad news, but you'll need to get familiar with the nitty gritty requirements of the XBRL format specification, understand the [XBRL Taxonomy](https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-2.1/REC-2003-12-31/XBRL-2.1-REC-2003-12-31+corrected-errata-2013-02-20.html#_5) the client wants to use, and build the code from that point forward.

That being said, there are a number of libraries to de/serialize XML in .NET. Start with the System.XML and System.XML.Schema namespaces to define your XBRL schema and generate/read your XML files.

You could also look into [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to convert tab delimited/csv/excel data into your objects (and vice versa). Specifically, look into the "Flattening" functionality there.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for give response. can you help me in programmatically ?